# css - move and expand flex box to take up half screen

Tags: html, css

I have a CSS Flex-box that currently sits in the middle/right of the screen.  I'm struggling to make the box full height and sit fully over the right hand side stretching from the center.  What I mean is I want it to sit on the right hand half of the screen (full height).

```
https://www.cajsoft.co.uk/test/visitor2.html
```

hope someone can help with my coding.  I'm very new to css.

```
https://jsfiddle.net/cajsoft/ruek825m/
```

Comment: post your code to demonstrate your issue here and clarify your question as much as possible if you really need help ;)

Comment: @G-Cyrillus The problem is I'm using someone else code and trying to adapt it so dont really know what part of the code controls it.. I posted the jsFiddle of the code above.

Comment: the question is yours and you turned the links into pieces of code to allow posting your question ... post the fiddle code here and a screen of the expected result :)

Answer (score 1):

You can do this adding the follow properties to your parameters class:

```
.parameters {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    width: 50vw;
    height: 100vh;
    <the rest of properties that you want>
 }
```

Comment: Thanks, nearly there!!  unfortunately, its too big for the browser window therefore scroll bars appear.   
https://www.cajsoft.co.uk/test/visitor2.html  @maurogandulfo

Comment: Add also 'box-sizing: border-box;'  for solve the scroll problem

Comment: Thanks, can I ask why it has made my buttons 3 times the size they were in height?  @maurogandulfo

Comment: It will be because there doesn't have a height property itself, add 'height: 50px;' to your .button2 class

Comment: Can I do "margin-top: 20vh;" to move the buttons down?  will this be responsive?

Comment: Check that I changed the left property in the code, and with respect to the other topic, to make responsive the element you will have to work more on the CSS (with media queries for example), because the element fill only half of the screen, and on small screens, it will be inaccessible.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229002/discussion-between-craig-johnstone-and-maurogandulfo).

Answer (score 1):

Assuming right-box class is the element you want sitting on the right and occupying the full height and half the screen. The following css will get it done

```css
.right-box {
    position: fixed;
    left: 50vw;
    top: 0px;
    width: 50vw;
    height: 100vh;
    background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="wright-box-container">
    <div class="right-box"></div>
</div>
```